# SPFile.OpenBinary - Encoding Issues

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, publishing-page, encoding

I am copying some SharePoint pages from one site collection to another and I noticed that certain special characters get mangled up in the destination file. Here is an example:

Source Text:

> Nous dialoguons avec les entreprises
>   pour générer des résultats positifs pour nos clients et la
>   collectivité.

Destination Text:

> Nous dialoguons avec les entreprises
>   pour gÃ©nÃ©rer des rÃ©sultats positifs pour nos clients et la
>   collectivitÃ©.

So far, I've narrowed down the problem to this portion of my code:

```
var bytes = sourceFile.OpenBinary();
var targetFile = targetFiles.Add(sourceFile.Name, bytes, new SPFileCollectionAddParameters()
{
    Overwrite = true,
    CheckInComment = "Migrated from " + sourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl,
    CheckRequiredFields = false,
});
```

I have considered converting the bytes to UTF-8 first before adding the new file:

```
var sourceBytes = sourceFile.OpenBinary();
byte[] convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, sourceBytes);
var targetFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(sourceFile.Name, convertedBytes, new SPFileCollectionAddParameters()
{
    Overwrite = true,
    CheckInComment = "Migrated from " + sourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl,
    CheckRequiredFields = false,
});
```

But this results in further mangling of additional characters:

> Nous dialoguons avec les entreprises pour gÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©rer des
>   rÃƒÂ©sultats positifs pour nos clients et la collectivitÃƒÂ©.

And if I try:

```
byte[] convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, sourceBytes);
```

I get this:

> Nous dialoguons avec les entreprises pour g??n??rer des r??sultats
>   positifs pour nos clients et la collectivit??.

It looks like I definitely need to convert the bytes from one encoding to another, but I just can't figure out the direction.

Please help.

**UPDATE:** I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

in the head section of my master page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly why this works, but I solved this problem by using this code:

```
byte[] convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF32, sourceBytes);
```

Hope that helps someone.